# Preparing a compare query between two database tables with similar columns

Tags: java, sql, db2, hsqldb

Given two tables each having n columns where 1 to n-1 columns are the columns which together form a unique key and the nth column is the value column, how can I create a generalized query in my java program which outputs 1 to n-1 columns, nth column of first table, nth column of second table and the difference of the nth column of the two tables.

For e.g. when n = 2, that is when given tables have two columns where first column is the key and the second column is the value, my query would be like:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(A.COL1, B.COL1) AS COL1, 
  CAST(A.VALCOL AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS SRC_TAB_VALUE, 
  CAST(B.VALCOL AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS TRGT_TAB_VALUE, 
  CAST(CAST(A.VALCOL AS DECIMAL(18,2)) - cast(B.VALCOL AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS DIFF_OF_VAL 
FROM 
  SCHEMA1.TAB1 A 
FULL JOIN 
  SCHEMA2.TAB2 B 
ON A.COL1 = B.COL1 
  ORDER BY COL1
```

I am preparing above query in my Java program. The diff query above runs against two in memory HSQL tables.

But how can I generalize this query when the number of key columns are greater then 1.

e.g. given two tables with 5 columns each, the combination of first 4 columns will create a unique key while the fifth column would be the value of that key which is to be compared.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: If your database is HSQL, why is this tagged DB2?  If DB2 is actually a target, which OS family does your DB2 server run on?

Comment: There _are_ tools to do table comparisons, so usually you don't even have to write any SQL.  Note that if you are attempting table comparisons, you need more than one statement, or you're going to miss some potential differences - where the **keys** are different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approaching your question differently, here is another answer.

If you want the SQL to be as generic as possible so that it is easy to generate in your Java, you could write it like this:

```
WITH 
  TABLEA (COL1,COL2,COLN) AS (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA1.TAB1),
  TABLEB (COL1,COL2,COLN) AS (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA2.TAB2)        
SELECT 
  COALESCE(TABLEA.COL1,TABLEB.COL1) AS COL1, 
  COALESCE(TABLEA.COL2,TABLEB.COL2) AS COL2, 
  TABLEA.COLN AS COLN_A, 
  TABLEB.COLN AS COLN_B, 
  (TABLEA.COLN-TABLEB.COLN) AS DIFF
FROM TABLEA
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLEB
  ON  TABLEA.COL1=TABLEB.COL1 
  AND TABLEA.COL2=TABLEB.COL2
;
```

The example is for 3 column tables. Anywhere where it has `COL2` should be replaced with `COL2`, `COL3`, ... `COLn-1` as suits the size of the tables. I see four places where this is necessary: the creation of `TABLEA`, the creation of `TABLEB` [note that these are identical, so the code only needs to generate the clause once and use it twice], the `SELECT COALESCE(TABLEA.COLn,TABLEB.COLn) AS COLn` and the `ON` clause `AND TABLEA.COLn=TABLEB.COLn`.

Obviously, you will also have to replace `SCHEMA1.TAB1` and `SCHEMA2.TAB2` as appropriate. The rest of the code should be generic and you don't need to use the actual column names, which should make the Java code much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is clearly written, it doesn't give enough details, such as *why would you do such a thing?*

Seriously, SQL isn't suited to "generalised queries". So you need to have a good reason for doing this in such a difficult way.

Also, your query has `SRC_TAB_VALUE` and `TRGT_TAB_VALUE` being cast as `DECIMAL(18,2)` when selected and when subtracted - why is this necessary, aren't they decimal to begin with? Are the `VALUE` columns always numeric? What about the key columns? They are being cast also, so are presumably numeric? If they contain non-numeric characters, the `CAST` will fail. Why is there no `WHERE` clause to limit your results?

And before coming up with some bizarre attempt at a SQL solution, I have to ask: Why can't the java code just generate the appropriate SQL itself?

It seems like this is a purposefully obtuse problem, one which shouldn't come up unless you are approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Agreed, although presumably he was planning on having Java generate the statement - otherwise it requires a stored proc.

Comment: If Java is generating the statement, and the tricky part is getting it to create an optimal statement, then this is a Java problem, not a DB2/SQL problem.

Perhaps I should have addressed it as if it read "How can I get my Java code to generate the SELECT, and are there any SQL/DB2 tricks to make that easier".